# Is possible to create a for loop feeding a SQL procedure with result set in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In an attempt to feed the result (owner, object_name) of a query into DBMS_STATS I've tried the following PL/SQL fragment:

```
DECLARE
  CCLOB  VARCHAR2(500);
  BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (
            select o.owner own,o.object_name obn
            from sys.col_group_usage$ cg,dba_objects o
             where cg.obj#=o.object_id
             group by owner,object_name
               )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.own||' '||rec.obn);
      SELECT dbms_stats.report_col_usage(ownname =>'''rec.own''', tabname =>'''rec.obn''') into CCLOB from dual;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CCLOB);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

but the result is:

```
DWI DWATOBP
ORA-20001: 'REC.OWN' is an invalid identifier

################SNPI#################

AGUN RDC
ORA-20001: 'REC.OWN' is an invalid identifier

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Some variations on the code with their errors:

a) with no quotes:

```
SELECT dbms_stats.report_col_usage(ownname =>rec.own, tabname =>rec.obn) into CCLOB from dual;

DWI DWATOBP
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 14
```

b) with 1 single quote:

```
SELECT dbms_stats.report_col_usage(ownname =>'rec.own', tabname =>'rec.obn') into CCLOB from dual;

DWI DWATOBP
ORA-20001: REC.OWN is an invalid identifier
```

c) with 2 single quotes:

```
SELECT dbms_stats.report_col_usage(ownname =>''rec.own'', tabname =>''rec.obn'') into CCLOB from dual;

ERROR at line 14:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 54:
PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06550: line 14, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: Well, look at the error message. The interpreter is confused about what you mean by `rec.own`.

Comment: Why have you declared the `CCLOB` variable as `varchar2(500)` when you're selecting a CLOB into it? If the function returns more than 500 characters you'll get 'numeric or value error', as you've seen with the single quotes removed from the call.

Comment: @Alex Poole    Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 2):

By passing the parameters in as '''rec.own''' and '''rec.obn''', you're actually passing in the strings: 'rec.own' and 'rec.obn'. Neither of which are valid identifier names!

Remove the single quotes, and it should work.

ETA: Also, change the variable CCLOB to be CLOB datatype, as dbms_stats.report_col_usage returns a CLOB.

Comment: --------with NO quotes
DWI DWATOBP
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 14
------- with 1 SINGLE QUOTES

DWI DWATOBP
ORA-20001: REC.OWN is an invalid identifier

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
-------with 2 SINGLE QUOTES
      SELECT dbms_stats.report_col_usage(ownname =>''rec.own'', tabname =>''rec.obn'') into CCLOB from dual;
                                                     *
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 54:
PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06550: line 14, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: dbms_stats.report_col_usage returns a clob. You've defined "CCLOB" to be VARCHAR2(500) ... change it to a CLOB and it should work. (At least, it does for me)

Comment: @Boneist Thanks very much.It works!  No quotes + CLOB var definition